# Can iOS8 CloudKit support streaming behind the scenes?

Tags: ios, azure, cloudkit

Is there any way, using currently available SDK frameworks on Cocoa (touch) to create a streaming solution where I would host my mp4 content on some server and stream it to my iOS client app?

I know how to write such a client, but it's a bit confusing on server side.

AFAIK cloudKit is not suitable for that task because behind the scenes it keeps a synced local copy of datastore which is NOT what I want. I want to store media content remotely and stream it to the client so that it does not takes precious space on a poor 16 GB iPad mini.

Can I accomplish that server solution using Objective-C / Cocoa Touch at all?

Should I instead resort to Azure and C#?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear why would you do anything like that?

If you have control over the server side, why don't you just set up a basic HTTP server, and on client side use AVPlayer to fetch the mp4 and play it back to the user? It is very simple. A basic apache setup would do the job.

If it is live media content you want to stream, then it is worth to read this guide as well:
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/StreamingMediaGuide.pdf

*Edited after your comment:*

If you would like to use AVPlayer as a player, then I think those two things don't fit that well. AVPlayer needs to buffer different ranges ahead (for some container formats the second/third request is reading the end of the stream). As far as I can see *CKFetchRecordsOperation* (which you would use to fetch the content from the server) is not capable of seeking in the stream.

If you have your private player which doesn't require seeking, then you might be able to use CKFetchRecordsOperation's *perRecordProgressBlock* to feed your player with data.

Comment: I want to create my private cloud that will host videos, so that my family can watch them via a custom client ios app. I want a custom app because none of the available solutions like shared photostream, youtube app..et..etc..are suitable. I don't want those videos to take up gigabytes of space on their iPads. (all have 16GB versions...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that with CloudKit. First, it is not true that CloudKit keeps a local copy of the data. It is up to you what you do with the downloaded data. There isn't even any caching in CloudKit.

To do what you want to do, assuming the content is shared between users, you could upload it to CloudKit in the public database of your app. I think you could do this with the CloudKit web interface, but otherwise you could create a simple Mac app to manage the uploads.

The client app could then download the files. It couldn't stream them though, as far as I know. It would have to download all the files.

If you want a streaming solution, you would probably have to figure out how to split the files into small chunks, and recombine them on the client app.

Comment: Perhaps you missed that, but I stressed in my original post that I don't want it to take up local space. When you say download do you really mean download or actually stream?

Comment: My idea was that you wouldn't download all the files, but just download one when you want to play it, store it temporarily, then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this [document](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/StreamingMediaGuide.pdf) is up-to-date, but there is paragraph "Requirements for Apps" which demands using HTTP Live Streaming if you deliver any video exceeding 10min. or 5MB.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I will not care though, since it is only for family purposes, so I will just push through Testflight and do whatever I want without Apple oversight.